# How to create initial revision for test objects when using django-reversion in test case

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-reversion

I'm creating some initial tests as I play with django-revisions. I'd like to be able to test that some of my api and view code correctly saves revisions.  However, I can't get even a basic test to save a deleted version.

```
import reversion
from django.db import transaction
from django import test
from myapp import models

class TestRevisioning(test.TestCase):
    fixtures = ['MyModel']
    def testDelete(self):
        object1 = models.MyModel.objects.first()
        with transaction.atomic():
             with reversion.create_revision():
                 object1.delete()
        self.assertEquals(reversion.get_deleted(models.MyModel).count(), 1)
```

This fails when checking the length of the deleted QuerySet with:

```
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

My hypothesis is that I need to create the initial revisions of my model (do the equivalent of `./manage.py createinitialrevisions`). If this is the issue, how do I create the initial revisions in my test? If that isn't the issue, what else can I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the solution is pretty simple. I saved my object under revision control.

```py
# imports same as question

class TestRevisioning(test.TestCase):
    fixtures = ['MyModel']

    def testDelete(self):
        object1 = models.MyModel.objects.first()
        # set up initial revision
        with reversion.create_revision():
            object1.save()
        # continue with remainder of the test as per the question.
        # ... etc.
```

I tried to override `_fixture_setup()`, but that didn't work. Another option would be to loop over the MyModel objects in the `__init__()`, saving them under reversion control.

Answer (score 0):

'MyModel' is the name of the file with your fixtures?
If not, what you probably is missing is the data creation.

You can use fixtures (but a file, not the name of your model) or factories.

There's a whole chapter in Django documentation related to providing initial data in database for models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/

Hope it helps

Comment: The MyModel object is correctly loaded from its fixture (MyModel.json). If it were not, `models.MyModel.objects.first()` would return `None`, and `object1.delete()` would raise an `AttributeError`.